# The use of universal properties to prove the existence of isomorphism

Tags: tensor-products, universal-property

I just start self learning tensor and I find the universal property is difficult to use.

I think I understand the basic concept of the universal property. The tensor product of $V_1, \cdots, V_m$, $(V,\gamma)$ satisfies $\forall f$, $\exists! T$, s.t. $f=T\gamma$.

\begin{array}{ccc}
V_1\times\cdots\times V_m &\rightarrow\gamma  & V\\
& \searrow f& \downarrow T\\
&& W\\
\end{array}

However, I came across some similar problems which I think they need the same trick on applying universal property, but I cannot figure it out.

Use universal properties to prove there is a canonical isomorphism:

(A) $S_r(V^*)\to S_r(V)^*$, $S_r(V)$ is the r-th symmetric power of V.

(B) $\bigwedge^i(V^*)\to (\bigwedge^iV)^*$

(C) $\bigwedge^2(V\oplus W)\to \bigwedge^2V\oplus(V\oplus W)\oplus\bigwedge^2W$

where $V$, $W$ are both finite dimension vector space.

Could anyone provide me some hint on how to use the universal property to find this isomorphism. I think they must use one common trick to do that, but I think my problem is I cannot find a proper pair like $(V, \gamma)$ to apply the universal property.

Thank you very much!

Comment: one must read: $\forall f$ **multilinear** $\exists T$ **linear** such that $f=T\circ\gamma$...

Comment: OK, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

One important thing you have not written is that though $V_1\times\dots\times V_n$ is a linear space if the $V_i$'s are, the maps $\gamma$ and $f$ from $V_1\times\dots\times V_n$ are *not* linear maps, but they are *mulitlinear*: linear in each variable (i.e. if values of the other variables are fixed).

Then the tensor product $V_1\otimes\dots\otimes V_n$ is another vector space, which make multilinear maps like $\gamma$ and $f$ *represent as a linear map*.

For the exterior power, for example, one can use the alternating multilinear maps.

We have one more important lemma, that we have to use:

> If $V$ and $V'$ both satisfy the universal property, then they are isomorphic.

Then, for example, for (B), prove that there is a map $(V^*)^i\to (\Lambda^iV)^*$ which is universal among all alternating multilinear maps $(V^*)^i\to W$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In your lemma, is $V'$ the same as $V^*$?

Comment: I am a little bit confused about the universal property. What do you exactly mean by "...is universal among..."? I mean, which "object" could have universal property? Which "object" could be universal? A map? A tensor product? A pair $(V, \gamma)$? So what do you mean by "... a map ... is universal among ...maps..."? Thank you very much!

Comment: $V'$ stands for another vectorspace, and probably I should have written $(V',\gamma')$ for clarity where $gamma'$ is a multilinear map $V_1\times\dots\times V_n\to V'$. Assuming both $(V,\gamma)$ and $(V',\gamma')$ satisfy the above universal property, by the uniqueness condition one can deduce $V\cong V'$. This lemma is true generally, so for example one can directly apply it to the case of altrernating multilinear maps.